# insufficient access rights on cross-reference id when changing pricebook2 field on Opportunity Object

Tags: insufficient-privileges

I know there are lots of articles about this error message and I've tried sorting through them, but so far I've founding nothing for this particular issue.

I have a user who can remove the pricebook lookup value and save the Opportunity, but if they try to add a pricebook to the field, they get the error "Review the errors on this page. insufficient access rights on cross-reference id"

The user is the owner of the Opportunity. I've given the user full CRUD access to Opportunity and verified that they have Read permissions on Pricebook.

It's just weird to me that the user was able to remove a price book, but not select one and save it.

We use CPQ in case that makes a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: were there opportunity Line items on the Opportunity? If so, what Pricebookentry->pricebook2 do they reference?